# HotKeySet() issue

Tags: autoit, xbmc, kodi

I cannot figure why this script does not work:

```
HotKeySet("^!k", "StartKodi")
StartKodi()

While 1
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

Func StartKodi()
   ShellExecute("C:\Program Files\Kodi\kodi.exe")
EndFunc
```

I would like to run the function only when the HotKeySet is pressed, But the HotKeySet does not start the function apparently....

Comment: in *what way* does it "not work"?

Comment: to not automatically start Kodi, remove the second line. Within the Function add `MsgBox(0,"ok","Fuction called")` to test if the Function is correctly started. Ìf it is, there is something wrong with starting Kodi (maybe you need to add a working folder to `ShellExecute')

Answer (score 0):

The first line `HotKeySet("^!k", "StartKodi")` sets the hotkey <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to run the function `StartKodi()` and then the second line, `StartKodi()` directly runs the function `StartKodi()`, so if you had intended for the `StartKodi()` function to *only* run when the hotkey is pressed (and not when the script is run), then this would explain the unintended behavior.

I don't know how Kodi works, but some applications only allow one instance to be run at a time, so if you had intended to run Kodi once when the script is run and then *also* via the hotkey, this could explain why it would not run when the hotkey is pressed.

Comment: But if I do :



HotKeySet("^!k", "StartKodi")

While 1
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

Func StartKodi()
   ShellExecute("C:\Program Files\Kodi\kodi.exe")
EndFunc


Still does not work….

E

Comment: I would like to run the function only when the HotKeySet is pressed.....